# Run time heap exception during memory deallocation

Tags: c, memory, malloc, heap-memory, free

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    static char* buf;

    buf = (char*)malloc(20*sizeof(char));

    scanf("%s",buf);

    while(buf[0] != NULL)
        printf("\n%s\n",buf++);

    free(buf);
    buf=NULL;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Message box during execution free(buf):

> Windows has triggered a breakpoint in clean_rough_draft.exe.
>
> This may be due to a corruption of the heap, which indicates a bug in
>   clean_rough_draft.exe or any of the DLLs it has loaded.
>
> This may also be due to the user pressing F12 while
>   clean_rough_draft.exe has focus.
>
> The output window may have more diagnostic information.

What's the reason? I just want to free memory without a leak...

Comment: change static char* buf; to char *buf;   And while(buf[0] != NULL) to while(buf[0] != 0), try again.

Comment: @laifjei Things that you pointed out doesn't matter.

Comment: @0x6B6F77616C74: They're not related to the crash, but in terms of "good practice" they're worth pointing out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you're incrementing `buf`, and then trying to `free()` it. By the time you `free()` it, it is no longer pointing to what `malloc()` returned.

Also (this isn't related to your crash), you probably should be checking `buf[0] != '\0'` instead of `buf[0] != NULL`.

Comment: I had checked it , but I thought there is a better way to implement this.

Comment: @0x6B6F77616C74: And what do you mean by "better?" You either have to keep a copy of the pointer, or you have to use an index counter (and not increment `buf`). Which you choose is entirely up to you. Although I would certainly say using `fgets()` (with `stdin`) instead of `scanf()` is better (because `scanf()` can lead to overflow errors)

Answer (score 1):

> Problem is "**printf("\n%s\n",buf++);**" i.e. you are changing the
>   base address returned by the "malloc" i.e. "buf". For "**free();**"
>   api you have to pass the base address returned by the "**malloc**"
>   api.
>
> **Alternative or Solution would be:**  Have an extra character pointer and temporarily store the base address returned by "**malloc**", if dynamic
>   allocation is successful. Re-storing it back while freeing the allocated memory.

```
 #include<stdio.h>
 #include<stdlib.h>

    int main()
    {
        static char* buf;
        static char *temp;

        buf = (char*)malloc(20*sizeof(char));
        /* Better to check for the allocation failure */
        if(!buf) 
        {
           printf("Failed to allocate memory \n");
           exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        } 
        else
        {
          temp = buf; 

          scanf("%s",buf);

          while(*buf != '\0')
              printf("\n%s\n",buf++);

          /* restoring the base address back to buf */
          buf = temp; 

          free(buf);
          buf=NULL;
          temp = NULL; 
        }

          return 0;
    }
```